# Alternative to innerHTML for IE select box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem that is  php  data not showing in select box. innerhtml not working in Internet Explorer. long_description_detail_list data not showing in select box.please help me

first page:

```
<div id="long_description_detail_list" style="display:none;">
    <option value="0">Select..</option>
    <?php
    include_once('Model/Language.php');
    $r = new Language();
    $a = $r->Select();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
    {
        print '<option value="'.$a[$i][0].'">'.$a[$i][1].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</div>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    //Browser Support Code
function create_long_description_detail_div(){
    if(count_table_long_description_detail() >=3) {
        alert("You can not add more than 3 long_description Details");
    }
    else {
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                var blank_long_description_detail = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                document.getElementById('long_description_detail_counter').value ++;
                $('#my-all-long_description_details-here').append(blank_long_description_detail);
                set_new_height_of_step_2('inc');
                var long_description_list_counter = document.getElementById('long_description_detail_counter').value;
                var long_description_detail_list = document.getElementById('long_description_detail_list').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('llanguage[' + long_description_list_counter + ']').innerHTML = long_description_detail_list;
            }
        }
        var long_description_detail_counter = document.getElementById('long_description_detail_counter').value;

        var queryString = "?long_description_detail_counter=" + long_description_detail_counter;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "Views/User/long_description/add_long_descriptions_detail.php" + queryString, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }
}


</script>
```

data not showing here in second page named add_long_descriptions_detail.php:

```
<select id="llanguage[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" name="llanguage[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" class="txtBox">
                            <option value="0">Select..</option>

                            </select>
```

Comment: this is the reason peole use jquery, it take cares of the browser specific issues

Comment: you need to add each option instead

Comment: What IE version(s) is the problem happening in? Also what IE versions do you need to support? (If you're only supporting IE7 upward, you can throw away the ActiveX stuff in your ajax function).

Comment: i am have not enough knowledge in jquery.will you help me Dagon?

Comment: i already check IE8 and IE10 but same problem @Spudley.
how can i use ActiveX stuff in my ajax function.
can you give correct code.

Comment: @Hashibulhasan - you already have activeX code. What I was saying is that you probably *don't* need it there. But this is not related to your original question.

Comment: This question really has zero to do with PHP. You should post your rendered HTML instead and kill the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn’t support updating the elements of a `<select>` with `innerHTML`, but what you can do is use the DOM, which is always the right way to go about things anyways.

Make your server-side script return a JSON array of options; it’ll make everything a lot easier.

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
        // Parse the response
        var options = eval('(' + ajaxRequest.responseText + ')');

        // Get the box; I have no clue what this is
        var box = document.getElementById('llanguage[' + long_description_list_counter + ']');

        // Clear any current elements
        while(box.childNodes.length > 0) {
            box.removeChild(box.firstChild);
        }

        // Add new ones
        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var newOption = document.createElement('option');
            newOption.value = options[i].value;
            newOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[i].text));
        }
    }
};
```

(This is a little trimmed-down from your original code, but I’m sure you can fit it in.)

It’s also probably a good idea to use an old-IE-compatible JSON parser instead of `eval`.

The JSON should look like this:

```
[
    { "text": "Some text", "value": "some-value" }
]
```

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to produce it conveniently from a PHP array.